# Does $\lim_ {(x,y)\to (0,0 )} \frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2 + y^2}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

My solution is the following:

approaching by the y-axis:

$\lim_ {(y)\to (0),(x=0)} =\lim_ {(y) \to (0)}=\frac{0+y^3}{0^2+y^2}=y=0$

approaching by $y=x$

$\lim_ {(y)\to (0),(y=x)} =\lim_ {y=x}=\frac{x^3+x^3}{x^2+x^2}=\frac{2x^3}{2x^2}=x=0$

So I think,that this limit exists.
is it correct in this form?

Comment: You need a bit more than this...

Comment: Please see my answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706300/is-the-domain-of-fx-y-dfracxyx2-y2-an-open-set-and-does-the-limi/1706315#1706315) maybe helpful. In fact, by polar method you can simply prove that this limit exist.

Comment: it's still a little bit complicated now

Comment: Consider $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ then you have $\lim_{r \to 0}r(\cos(\theta)^3+\sin(\theta)^3)=0$ and finish.

Comment: so the limit exists and it will be $0$?

Comment: Yah if the answer of limit be independent of $\theta$ it means the limit exist and has the value that you obtained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:
$$
\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=x\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}+y\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}
$$

But your method doesn't answer the question.

Comment: $\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ is less then $0$ and $\frac{y^2}{x^2 + y^2}$ is also less then $0$

Comment: and $x$ goes to $0$, $y$ goes to $0$ so the limit will be $0$?

Comment: @Zauberkerl Yes. To be precise $0\leq|\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}|\leq|x|+|y|$.

Answer (score 3):

Since a limit is being taken as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ we may assume that $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ during the approach, and so write $x=r \cos t, y=r \sin t.$ [Here $r>0$ is unique, and $t$ is determined mod $2\pi.$] Then your function is $r \cdot (\cos ^3 t+ \sin ^3 t),$ whose magnitude is less than $2r$ and so goes to $0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ through values other than $(0,0).$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Use polar coordinates: $(x,y)\to (0,0)\iff r\to 0$. In polar coordinates, thexpression becomes
$$\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}=r(\cos^3\theta+\sin^3\theta).$$

Comment: Please first read comments and after that make an answer. Thanks

Comment: @Amin235 you do know you could've posted the answer too instead of just commenting it.

Comment: I know that using polar coordinates to disprove continuity works fine, but to prove continuity it is not. Am I missing something here?

Comment: If $r$ tends to $0$, as the second factor is bounded, the product tends to $0$, so the limit exists and is $0$. I don't see any problem with using polar coordinates.

Comment: @Bernard Then how would that work for $z=\frac{x^3}{y^2+x^3}$ at $(0,0)$? Does this limit exist using polars?

Comment: @imranfat: It doesn't work in this case, since the denominator may be, depending on the polar angle, $r^2\sin^2\theta$ or $r^3\cos^3\theta$ (or the sum of both), yielding a different limit in both cases. I didn't say using polar coordinates can yield an answer in all possible situations. I only say it can be a useful tool.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for getting back.

Answer (score -2):

Try coming at it from any other direction, e.g. y = mx.

Ced

Comment: No. There are known examples, where limits in every (linear) direction are identical, but the limit doesn't exist.